# React/Redux cannot read 'prop' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-props

I'm having trouble accessing a property of a props object. I can console log the entire object but if I try and console log the property it says the object isn't there.

```
class SingleCase extends Component {
  componentDidlMount() {
    this.props.getCurrentCase(this.props.location.id);
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props.current_case); // This works (Shows the object)
    console.log(this.props.current_case.description); // This fails with current_case is undefined

    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.props.current_case.description}</h2>
      </div>
    ); // this won't find the description in undefined
  }
}
export const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  current_case: state.cases.current_case,
});
//, { getFullGrievance }
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getCurrentCase })(SingleCase);
```

Is it a timing thing? There is no async request, to get the current case the action searches through an already established list and finds the one I need. Is the render getting run before props is set? If so, why can I view the entire props properly but not the one part I need?

Answer (score 0):

In reducr intiail state i think you have just defined current_case:{}....instead try `current_case:{description:""}`

Answer (score 0):

@karani jaswanth is correct. It have another solution. Use inline condition.

```
this.props?.current_case?.description
```